# Unable to create Dataproc cluster using custom image

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc, google-apis-explorer

I am able to create a google dataproc cluster from the command line using a custom image:

> gcloud beta dataproc clusters create cluster-name --image=custom-image-name

as specified in https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images, but I am unable to find information about how to do the same using the v1beta2 REST api in order to create a cluster from within airflow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Georges, you can take a look at this url: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.regions.clusters/create

Comment: Looks like that interface does not know the "image" parameter (yet)?

Comment: In the request body, you can build something like `{
  "clusterName": "",
  "config": {
    "softwareConfig": {
      "imageVersion": ""
    }
  }
}`...it seems that `imageVersion` is the right one.

Comment: I think 'imageVersion' actually refers to the Dataproc version (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions), not a custom image (which is a beta feature)

Comment: You're looking for "imageUri" on masterConfig and workerConfig objects: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/ClusterConfig#InstanceGroupConfig

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the right way to go. Still getting an "Unknown Error" (Http 500) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since custom images can theoretically reside in a different project if you grant read/use access of that custom image to whatever project service account you use for the Dataproc cluster, images currently always need a full URI, not just a short name.

When you use gcloud, there's syntactic sugar where gcloud will resolve the full URI automatically; you can see this in action if you use `--log-http` with your gcloud command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create foo --image=custom-image-name --log-http
```

If you created one with gcloud you can also `gcloud dataproc clusters describe` your cluster to see the fully-resolved custom image URI.

Comment: That nailed it. Thanks very much!